# Is it possible to get a list of nested collections from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I realise that similar questions have been asked but I could find nothing specific to suit my needs.

My current Firestore structure looks something like this.
Root Collection/Nested Document/Nested Collection.
An example would be:
Books/BooksA-C/ListOfBooksBetweenA-C.

I know that to access the list of docs nested under a collection, you can do something like this:

```
    db.collection('rootCollection').get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(docObj => {
        console.log(docObj.data());
      })
    })
```

How would I access a list of collections, nested under rootCollection/doc? I don't want to get the data of a specific nested collection, I would like to list all entries in my subcollection.

My current attempt is something like this (it throws an error, but hopefully it will add more context):

```
      db.collection('rootCollection').
      doc('nestedDoc').
      collection('nestedCollection').
      get().
      then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(nestedCollection => {
          console.log(nestedCollection .data().code);
        })
      })
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Edit: From what I have read from the documents, it does not seem possible, but I just wanted to clarify on the possibility. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to get a list of collections from the client-side SDKs, although the functionality *does* exist in the server-side SDKs.